# How to add median and IQR to seaborn violinplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to add the median and IQ values to the violin plot. However, I didn't find its argument.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.violinplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex",
                    data=tips, palette="Set2", split=True,
                    scale="count", inner="quartile")
plt.show()
```

[image: Violin Plot]

For instance, I want such a notation for all of the graphs per gender:

[image: Violin plot new]

I am fine to do it with other packages if it is available for them. However, I want to have violin plots rather than boxplots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the lines in `ax` you can see that they contain the coordinates of the quartile and median lines (see below)

So we could just take the non-zero element from the first array in each line, and the first element of the second array to get the x and y, and use the y as the text value.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,14)})
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex",
                    data=tips, palette="Set2", split=True,
                    scale="count", inner="quartile")

for l in ax.lines:
    ax.text(l.get_data()[0][l.get_data()[0].nonzero()][0], l.get_data()[1][0], f'{l.get_data()[1][0]:.0f}',size='large')
```

[image]

```
for l in ax.lines:
    print(l.get_data())
```

Output

```
(array([-0.33143126,  0.        ]), array([13.6975, 13.6975]))
(array([-0.37082654,  0.        ]), array([16.975, 16.975]))
(array([-0.25003508,  0.        ]), array([22.36, 22.36]))
(array([0.        , 0.38725949]), array([12.1625, 12.1625]))
(array([0.        , 0.39493527]), array([13.785, 13.785]))
(array([0.        , 0.25722566]), array([18.675, 18.675]))
(array([0.61440819, 1.        ]), array([12.235, 12.235]))
(array([0.62200517, 1.        ]), array([17.215, 17.215]))
(array([0.71996702, 1.        ]), array([26.0825, 26.0825]))
(array([1.        , 1.27676537]), array([11.35, 11.35]))
(array([1.        , 1.35376254]), array([15.38, 15.38]))
(array([1.        , 1.33610081]), array([16.27, 16.27]))
(array([1.63945286, 2.        ]), array([13.905, 13.905]))
(array([1.60991669, 2.        ]), array([18.24, 18.24]))
(array([1.75431475, 2.        ]), array([24.165, 24.165]))
(array([2.        , 2.17418026]), array([14.05, 14.05]))
(array([2.        , 2.18356376]), array([18.36, 18.36]))
(array([2.        , 2.12950778]), array([25.5625, 25.5625]))
(array([2.62638135, 3.        ]), array([15.135, 15.135]))
(array([2.61919886, 3.        ]), array([20.725, 20.725]))
(array([2.73148987, 3.        ]), array([26.55, 26.55]))
(array([3.        , 3.12054879]), array([15.175, 15.175]))
(array([3.        , 3.12176923]), array([17.41, 17.41]))
(array([3.        , 3.07327664]), array([24.8975, 24.8975]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you make their font larger for readability when printed?

Comment: @Hadij you can change the size parameter to a number and make it larger